# Container View controller variables are set to default when calling notification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicontainerview

I have a container view controller containing a tableview. In parent view controller I access the container view using the code below to set some variables and send notifications to reload the table view. But when the container view recieves notification from parent  it sets all variables to default and nothing is loaded into the table:

in parent view controller :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let containerVC= storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"detailContainerVC") as! ContainerViewController

//   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(containerVC,
//                                           animated: false)

containerVC.section1RowCount = self.basicDataCount
containerVC.section2RowCount = self.checkDataCount
containerVC.GroupDetail = self.GroupDetail
containerVC.price = self.price
//containerVC.detailTable.reloadData()
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "fillDataDetail"), object: nil)
```

So how can I set this container view variables in parent view controller?

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by sending parameters using userInfo in notification